# How to create masks in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

objectToBeMasked.mask = maskObject;

Ok, simple... but I can SEE the maskObject unless I set its alpha to 0 and then it doesn't let clicks through to objectToBeMasked

And every single tutorial that I've seen fails to mention this and how to solve it, as if it should be obvious.

How do I mask objects through AS3 so that the masks act like masks act like the ones added in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't see the mask. Probably the mask and the masked object are not on the stage at the time you are trying to apply the mask.

Can you pass on some code here?

Comment: yeah, you're right. I created the mask and masked the object in a loop and instead of reporting an error it made the mask visible and act like a normal sprite (except it hid the objectToBeMasked). I can be so stupid sometimes

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example :

```
var maskedShape : Shape = new Shape();
maskedShape.graphics.beginFill(0x0);
maskedShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
maskedShape.graphics.endFill();
addChild(maskedShape);
```

var maskerShape : Shape = new Shape();
maskerShape.graphics.beginFill(0x0);
maskerShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
maskerShape.graphics.endFill();
addChild(maskerShape);
maskerShape.x = 20;
maskerShape.y = 20;

maskedShape.mask = maskerShape;

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to not render your object simply bt setting `visible` parameter to false :

```
maskObject.visible = false;
```

so your `objectToBeMasked` is still masked, but do not catch mouse event, and is not rendered anymore :)